# Strange XML File That Loads in Word And Converting "Word" Document To PDF In PHP

Tags: php, xml, pdf, ms-word

Please see the screenshot below. I have been sent this file from a client. The file is exported from another piece of software and it loads up in word as a fully styled and presented document, but the filename as "xml" extension.

This is a bit confusing, the document starts in the source as XML but then has a load of what looks like encrypted garbage after it, so it's not XML at all is it? So I don't quite understand why their software marks it as XML when it's not.

My second question is: Is this actually a word document? Normally it would be .doc or .docx, I have never seen a word document saved with .xml before.

Final question: How would we now then use php to convert this to a PDF? I don't mind using third party software installed on the server and run via command line, I just need to figure out how to convert this. I could do it in C# but it's preferred in PHP so that our backend server can do the work rather than the desktop software we have that links with it.

[image]

Comment: This is a Word document, saved in the Word 2003 XML file format. This was an "interim" alternative - sort of an experimental stage of the full-fledged Open XML file formats introduced in Office 2007. What you're seeing is binary. This could be because the document was password protected, or it could be macro code. Images would be in Base64 - could be that. Hard to say without being able to see more of the document.

Comment: Without knowing more it's not possible to answer your last question, except that it would probably make most sense to open it using the Automation Services if this needs to be done server-side, or open and save to another format in Word.